# How do I create a "jumping" circle in Java GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, graphics

I would like to have a red filled circle at some place in my window. After the click on the circle, the circle should jump from the original place to a new one (disappear from the old place and appear on the new one). What would be the best way to do it?

I also would like to know how to draw a filled circle in Java. Are there any simple tools to do it? Or may be the easiest way is to use an image created by some other software?

**ADDED:**

For the beginning I would like to have just a redraw (a circle disappear and at "the same moment" it appears on the new position). I think it will be simple that some visual effects and I would like to start from the simples possible choice.

Comment: Do you want an animated action for the jump or just a redraw for the circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using Swing, Graphics2D and a custom JPanel. The tutorial contains a similar example:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html